# Set 'Autocommit=false' with Airflow Snowflake Operator

Tags: transactions, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've got a simple DAG that is designed to be committed as one transaction. I'm using Airflow for this use case as Snowflake won't allow Transaction control in Stored Procedures or Tasks.

When looking at my task log for a specific Task that is responsible for beginning the transaction, I noticed that auto-commit is set to true on each connection:

```
[2020-05-01 09:19:07,460] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2020-05-01 09:19:07,460] {{cursor.py:525}} INFO - query: [ALTER SESSION SET autocommit=True]
```

I need to set this property to false, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Dug into the package code at https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/operators/snowflake_operator.py

Noticed that upon Snowflake operator init, you can set the auto-commit property there to false.

I can confirm that after setting this property value, the log reflect this:

```
[2020-05-01 11:05:24,817] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2020-05-01 11:05:24,817] {{cursor.py:525}} INFO - query: [ALTER SESSION SET autocommit=False]
```

Comment: Good to hear that you found the option. Alternatively, I believe you can also use the Snowflake operator with a SQL `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` statement to make sure everything is executed in one transaction.

Comment: Hi Simon, thank you for the advice. I noticed some examples used this technique. Am I right in thinking that you can just give the Snowflake Operator a dictionary of SQL Statements and provided you start with BEGIN and end with COMMIT, all the statements are executed as one transaction?

Comment: Yes. You can pass a *List*, not a dictionary, of strings or just a single string to be run. If you have a look at the DBAPI operator (which the Snowflake operator inherits) you can see that all of the SQL statements are executed in a loop and then a single commit is done at the end (if you've got `autocommit` set to `false`). If you keep `autocommit` set to `true` however (the default) you can still do everything in a single transaction executing passing a `BEGIN` as the first statement.